# Rotating a Quad in Shader

Tags: glsl, opengl-es

I'm working Opengles2 and I have a just a texture ID and a quad from an SDK and its shader, and I can not access their code, just the vertex and pixel shader.

The quad from the SDK is rotated and flipped. Is it possible to rotate the quad and flip its sides in shader ?

I don't have also the MVP matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

multiply the quad's vertex positions by a rotation matrix that will give you the orientation you want

Comment: This answer would be better if it included an example of how to construct such a rotation matrix to achieve a particular rotation.

Answer (score 0):

For flipping and rotating the sides I would only change the texture coordinates.

Let's say that `(s, t)` are the texture coordinates, then assuming the texture covers the whole quad:

- change it to `(t, s)` for flipping the quad over its diagonal.
- change it to `(1 - t, s)` for flipping the quad over the `s` axis.
- change it to `(t, 1 - s)` for flipping the quad over the `t` axis.
- compse these for other results.

Read about [symmetry group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_(mathematics)#Second_example:_a_symmetry_group) for a more philosophical view.

Comment: can you show a simple pseudo code shader ?